# How to mock useRef hook with react-native using enzyme

Tags: react-native, jestjs, hook, enzyme, use-ref

I would like to write tests for my React-native app. My parent component will execute the methods within the child component.
My child component is using the Hooks forwardRef, useImperativeHandle, Ref as seen below

childs.tsx

```
export interface RefChild {
    toggle: () => void,
    close: () => void
}

const Child = forwardRef((props: ChildProps, ref: Ref<RefChild>) => {
    const [isVisible, setIsVisible] = useState(false);
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ toggle, close }));

    const toggle = () => {
        setIsVisible(!isVisible);
    }

    const close = () => {
        setIsVisible(false)
    }

    return (...mycomponent)
}
```

My Parent component is catching the 'ref' call with

```
ref={(el: RefChild) => childRef.current = el}
```

Which allows me to call the 'toggle' and 'close' methods from within the Parent.
Now, I fail to understand how to do the same thing within my test

my parent-test.tsx:

```
describe('Parent', () => {
    let wrapper: ShallowWrapper;
    let props: any;
    beforeEach(() => {
        props = createTestProps({});
        wrapper = shallow(<Parent {...props} />);
    });

//this is what I am currently trying to do, but not working
//test 1 (not working)
    it("useRef child", () => {
        const useRefSpy = jest.spyOn(React, 'useRef').mockReturnValueOnce({ current: <Child/> });
        expect(useRefSpy).toBeCalled();
        useRefSpy.current.toggle();
    })

//test 2 (not working)
    it("useRef child2", () => {
        const ref = {
            current: {
                toggle: jest.fn(),
                close: jest.fn()
            }
        }

        ref.current.toggle();
    })

//test 3 (not working)
    it("useRef child3", () => {
        wrapper.instance().childref.current.toggle(); //failing as functional components don't have instance
    })
})
```

My versions of React and RN are:

```
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.3"
```

Could anyone explain me how should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question there is no `instance` in `functional` component, I think there is a better way to handle `toggle` and `close` functions from `parent component` using a boolean `prop` for each of them and the listen to changes in this value like this:

you have a state in parent component called `isClose` set to false and then in child component you use something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
   if(isClose){
     //call close function
     close()
   }
}, [isClose])
```

But by the way in your current setup I think you need to mock the `useRef` hook something like this:

```
const useRefSpy = jest
  .spyOn(React, "useRef")
  .mockReturnValueOnce(() => ({ current: <Child /> }));
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I see what you mean by using the useEffect.
if I render the child like ```<Child isClosed={isClosed}/>``` how can I make  the useEffect run?

Comment: you use the `useEffect` I mentioned above in the `Child` Component and pass an `isClosed` prop to `Child` like you mentioned and whenever you want to run the `effect` just pass a true flag to `isClosed` prop like this:  ```<Child isClosed={true}/>```

Comment: Hi, apologies for the delay, christmas took more of my time than planned :).
ultimately, this is working, it also removes the need of my Child's ref. However when I change the value isClosed from the Parent (to modify the child) it re-render my parent as the state is in the Parent. I was using ref to be able to alter the Child state only so that my Child only will re-render. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Merry Christmas. So I think you have to go with mocking `useRef` as I've showed you in `useRefSpy` example

Comment: Hi, I am not able to call the toggle and close fct that way. I am doing ```useRefSpy.current.toggle()``` and it just fails